# Two overlapping ImageViews in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-resources

In a ViewGroup I want to put two ImageViews overlapping: The **imageview A** have a transparent background and some drawing across the image, the **imageview B**.

I want both them to be at the same place and have the same size (but can't fix their size in the XML because if the image at ivB changes the ivA should resize to match the new size.

Since the **ivA** source image does not change I tried ivA.getWidth() and **ivA**.getHeight() for setting the **ivB** size but their value are 0,0 in the onCreate() method.

Is there some "easy" way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the ImageView and in onLayout() you can get proper width or height after calling super.onLayout(). Try setting values in the place.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the dimensions in `onWindowFocusChangedListener`.

An easier way would be putting the ImageViews in a FrameLayout (which is built to put Views on top of the other), and resize the FrameLayout instead.